# How can I parse out the dimensions for this string in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, parsing

I am trying to parse out the individual dimensions (length, height, width) for a string in Excel but am having problems determining which text formulas to use.  Details below.

**Data example (in one cell):**
1 5/8 x 8 x 5/8

**Desired Output (in individual cells):**
Cell 1: '1 5/8'
Cell 2: '8'
Cell 3: '5/8'

Comment: I direct you to this answer [Microsoft Excel Macro](http://superuser.com/a/633924/228536). You can easily adapt that solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim out portions of the string, based on finding the "x" in your string. Will this be for only one cell or many?

To get things started with how the trimming could be accomplished: assuming the string is in cell **A1**, and you want the first part of the dimension in **B1**, you could put this formula in **B1**:
`=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("x",A1,1)+2))`

The LEFT function returns the left portion of a string. LEN returns the length, and FIND searches for one string within another.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, using the find() function to locate the two 'x' values and parsed out the first, second and third portions of the string in conjunction with the left() and right() functions

Comment: Aaron, since this was marked as accepted, could you please expand your answer to include a little more explanation (what Gryphoenix said), and not end it in a question? Otherwise this would have been more suitable as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the answer to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/540244/150988) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/627382/150988) give examples of how to use Excel’s capabilities to do this sort of thing.